# Invalid property name for size_hint in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

I am doing a kivy tutorial (FreeCodeCamp)
When I use the size_hint property for my button, it gives an error for invlid property name
Code:
Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class BoxLayoutExample(BoxLayout):
    pass
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #     self.orientation = "vertical"  # There is also horizontal
    #     b1 = Button(text="Button 1")
    #     b2 = Button(text="Button 2")
    #     b3 = Button(text="Button 3")
    #     self.add_widget(b1)
    #     self.add_widget(b2)
    #     self.add_widget(b3)


class MainWidget(Widget):
    pass


class TheLabApp(App):
    pass


TheLabApp().run()
```

Kivy File:

```
BoxLayoutExample:


<BoxLayoutExample>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "A"
        size_hint = 1, .5
    Button:
        text: "B"
        size_hint = 1, 2
    Button:
        text: "C"
        size_hint = 1, 1
```

Error:

```
kivy.lang.parser.ParserException: Parser: File "kv file path", line 25:
 ...
      23:    Button:
      24:        text: "A"
 >>   25:        size_hint = 1, .5
      26:    Button:
      27:        text: "B"
 ...
 Invalid property name
```

This same code works for the person giving the tutorial.

Comment: Is `size_hint` something defined in a newer version of `kivy` than you are using?

Comment: Replace `size_hint = 1, .5` with `size_hint: 1, .5`. Same for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to replace `=` with `:` like this:

```
BoxLayoutExample:


<BoxLayoutExample>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        text: "A"
        size_hint: 1, .5
    Button:
        text: "B"
        size_hint: 1, 2
    Button:
        text: "C"
        size_hint: 1, 1
```